# Understanding app.use('/', routes);

Tags: express

I have generated a sample app using express generator and inside `app.js` there is

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

There are two files generated `index.js` and `users.js`

To use the code inside the files there are this lines

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

My question,is `app.use('/', routes);` represent `index.js`  and `app.use('/users', users);` represent `users.js`?.

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

app.use gets the URL prefix you want ('/', '/users') and the route handler for it.
This allows modularity in your server side routing.

Cheers

Comment: Great. What if i add a function in users,how do i get to use it? i.e to do http://localhost:3000/users/logan

Comment: I don't remember what express generates but in order to do so you need to use the query property in req. Meaning when you go to localhost:3000/users/?id=logan – user3272483, you req.query.id will give you what you need.